# how to convert 10 digit number field to string field in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i want to update mobile field to string in mongodb.

```
{
"_id": "1373b7723",
"firstname": "name1",
"mobile":1000000099
},
{
"_id": "137be30723",
"firstname": "name2",
"mobile":1000000088
}
```

i need an output like this.

```
{
"_id": "1373b7723",
"firstname": "name1",
"mobile":"1000000099"
},
{
"_id": "137be30723",
"firstname": "name2",
"mobile":"1000000088"
}
```

```
db.users.updateMany(
    {}, //To match all documents
    [{ $set: {mobile: { $concat: [ "", "$mobile" ] } } }], 
    {
        new: true, 
        runValidators : true
    });
```

i tried with the above code but its not getting the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar earlier, but it was not conversion to string but to Date. See [this](https://kiranvj.com/blog/blog/mongodb-change-the-data-type-of-a-field/)

You can also use `$toString` as mentioned [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toString/). See [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toString/#example) example similar to your use case

Try below if it works for you.

```
db.users.find({}).forEach(function (doc) {
  db.users.updateOne(
    {
      _id: doc._id,
    },
    {
      $set: {
        mobile: String(doc.mobile)
      },
    }
  )
})
```

or modified version of your code

```
db.users.updateMany(
    {}, //To match all documents
    [{ $set: {mobile: { $toString: {$toLong:"$mobile"}  } } }], 
    {
        new: true, 
        runValidators : true
    });
```

Comment: from modified version of your code I'm getting  "9.87654e+09" for this number 987653009. but i want "987653009". thank you.

Comment: @saikrishna  I have updated the solution, please if that works - `{ $toString: {$toLong:"$mobile"}  }`

Comment: This worked for me ..{ $toString: {$toLong:"$mobile"} }. thanks